# API manager. Exception when URLis without version number

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0. If I publish API and subscribe and then call this API with version number, all is OK. Default version of API is checked. When I send request to this API without version in URL I get exception:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-05-06 07:23:01,782] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtFaultHandler} -  Cannot publish event. null {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtFaultHandler}
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:552)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtFaultHandler.mediate(APIMgtFaultHandler.java:76)
at    org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:84)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)

at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:220)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:389)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:97)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:65)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:295)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:317)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:149)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Our API manager is configured to work with WSO2 IS 5.1.0 and WSO2 DAS.

Comment: This exception stack trace doesn't look like problem with default endpoint. Can you please check your backend service connectivity? Also, add two/three line before this logs, so that we can identify the root cause of this error.

Comment: I'm very sorr.y. Of course there was message before exception: No matching resource found in the API for the given request. But why do I get such message. Request with version:

Comment: https://server:port/name1/name2/1.0/parameter and without version: https://server:port/name1/name2/parameter. Do I have to insert in context {version} uri variable?

Comment: There is one more message before exception: Cannot publish event . null

Comment: If you check the API as default version and published it, then you don't need to provide version. This was tested and verified in APIM 1.10 release. Have you re-published the API if you have edited the API and made it default

Comment: Yes, I have. After some tests I can make only one conclusion: if I use a path or query parameter I can't use endpoint without version. Endpoint without parameters  and without version works properly. Adding parameter causes endpoint not to work.

Comment: Can you provide working URL and non working URL, so that we can reproduce and fix this.

Comment: Working url: http://server:8284/test/1.0/4506, where 4506 is path parameter. Non working http://server:8284/test/4506

Comment: Could we expect some decision on our problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue will be fixed in the next release and you can use following workaround in order to solve the issue.

**For existing APIs**

- Edit the synapse config file of the default api which is in /repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api folder.

Ex: 
File name of Version API - admin--CountryTest_v1.0.0.xml, 
File name of default API - admin--CountryTest.xml

- Replace the uri-template value inside the resource tag and save the file.

  - current value - uri-template="$util.escapeXml($resource.getUriTemplate())"
  - new value     - uri-template="/*"

**For new APIs**

You can change the default_api_template.xml file in order to apply the fix for new APIs.

- Edit the default_api_template.xml which is in /repository/resources/api_templates folder replace the resource tag from the new value.

Current Value -

```
<resource xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
    #if($resource.getUriTemplate().contains("{") ||
       ($resource.getUriTemplate().contains("*") && !$resource.getUriTemplate().endsWith("/*")))
        uri-template="$util.escapeXml($resource.getUriTemplate())"
    #else
       url-mapping="$resource.getUriTemplate()"
    #end
        methods="$resource.getMethodsAsString()" faultSequence="fault">
```

New Value -

```
<resource methods="POST PATCH GET DELETE HEAD PUT OPTIONS"
         uri-template="/*"
         faultSequence="fault">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your use case but for me, it's working fine. Can you please double check whether that API was properly saved and published after you checked the **Make this the Default Version** check box.
You can check it by listing APIs(Metadata-> list-> API) in the carbon console and then click on the API name.

I simply tested it using the **CalculatorAPI** sample which takes some query parameters. I just published the samples and I subscribed to the **CalculatorAPI**. Below is the findings.

Just after the publish(without checked the **Make this the Default Version** check box)

**1st API call with version**

```
curl -k -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer afbbb795dadf272cec9c44efc78dc81b" "https://192.168.1.4:8243/calc/1.0/add?x=2&y=2"
```

**Response**

```
{"answer": "4.0"}
```

**2nd API call without version**

```
curl -k -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer afbbb795dadf272cec9c44efc78dc81b" "https://192.168.1.4:8243/calc/add?x=2&y=2"
```

**response**

```
am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>404</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Not Found</am:message><am:description>The requested resource (/calc/add?x=2&amp;y=2) is not available.</am:description></am:fault>
```

Then I edited the API and checked the **Make this the Default Version** check box and then published the API. Now I called the API and below is the output.

**1st API call with version**

```
curl -k -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer afbbb795dadf272cec9c44efc78dc81b" "https://192.168.1.4:8243/calc/1.0/add?x=2&y=2"
```

**Response**

```
{"answer": "4.0"}
```

**2nd API call without version**

```
curl -k -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer afbbb795dadf272cec9c44efc78dc81b" "https://192.168.1.4:8243/calc/add?x=2&y=2"
```

**response**

```
{"answer": "4.0"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll test this one more time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found  a answer or some reason why endpoint without version doesn't work. If I put some parameter to URL Pattern in API definition (for instance /a/{param}, or /a?param={param}, the resource in API description (xml file) is generated with attribute **url-template**=/a/{param} and in this case such endpoint doesn't work without version. If I remove {param} from URL pattern and insert parameter by button "Add Parameter" - endpoint without version (default) works OK. In this case in API description resource is generated with attribute **url-mapping** not with url-template (like in ESB, there are two types of URL in resource, I think).

So, I have to refuse to use path and query parameters explicitly in URL pattern when I wont to use endpoints without version (default).

Maybe there are some workaround?

There is some additional small question. If I wonted to add "path" parameter by pushing button ADD Parameter in GUI I couldn't do it, because of there aren't option "path" in select list, there are query, header, formData only.